# How to make an "edge blur" effect smooth in imagemagick?

Tags: image, imagemagick, alpha, blur, imagemagick-convert

Here is the source image:
[image: src image]

The imagemagick command I've tried is:

```
convert ddd.png -alpha set -virtual-pixel transparent \
-channel A -blur 0x10  -level 0,90% +channel \
-background transparent -layers flatten edge_blured.png
```

In the output, the blurred image edges are clipped.
[image]

How do I make the edges smooth?

Answer (score 2):

This is a localized event of the source image. The clipping happens because you have adjusted the alpha channel, but *not* the non-alpha image data underneath.

```
convert ddd.png -alpha off ddd_no_alpha.png
```

[image: ddd_no_alpha.png]

Applying the altered alpha channel to this image and you will see there's not enough background to cover the new space, as well as a missing square in the bottom right.

I would recommend isolating the image channel + effects to a new image mask.

```
convert ddd.png -alpha extract -blur 0x10 -alpha off mask.png
```

[image: mask.png]

And then rebuild the original image with adjusted alpha channel.

```
convert -size 550x550 'xc:#D0BCBE' mask.png -alpha off \
        -compose CopyOpacity -composite edge_blured.png
```

[image: edge_blured.png]